# Is it possible to make two GADBannerView on one Screen(UIViewController)?

Tags: ios, adbannerview

[image]

I am using GADBannerView in my app for ads. However I am unable to show two ads on one screen as shown in image.

How can I get this purpose, Please any info or help?

Comment: Hi @Duaan did you get any success ? I need the solution for the same case